# LiveWallPaper Change notifications in Android

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Just wondering whether its possible to detect LiveWallPaper changes in Android. I looked into ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED already. It works only for Wallpapers not for LiveWallpapers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It isn't perfect, but if you put a wallpaper check method in onResume it should work because the wallpaper would have probably been changed by a separate activity which means your activity has been paused. This won't work if the wallpaper was changed from some background code, but that doesn't normally happen especially for live wallpapers. That is how it is done in ADWLauncher.